# Creating an Automatic NFT trader

Tags: solidity, nft, opensea

(Apologies for keeping the questions so broad but not sure of the starting point at this stage)

Hi All,

I am trying to build an automatic NFT trader where a smart contract will buy the NFT from OpenSeas based on certain input conditions.
Any suggestions on how I can move forward would be appreciated

**My current approach:**
It seems that when one tries to buy an NFT at Opensea then a public function get triggered called atomicMatch_ (below is the function as per [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b#code)(couldn't locate the actual contract in Opensea GitHub page)). I was thinking a way by which my contract can trigger this public function but not being to able do it.
So wanted to know
a) If this is the best way to move forward or is there any simpler method
b) If this is the way forward how can get the details of the inputs required to trigger the function. I am not able to figure it out from the etherscan contract

Thanks
Rwiju
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
function atomicMatch_(
    address[14] addrs,
    uint[18] uints,
    uint8[8] feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls,
    bytes calldataBuy,
    bytes calldataSell,
    bytes replacementPatternBuy,
    bytes replacementPatternSell,
    bytes staticExtradataBuy,
    bytes staticExtradataSell,
    uint8[2] vs,
    bytes32[5] rssMetadata)
    public
    payable
{

    return atomicMatch(
      Order(addrs[0], addrs[1], addrs[2], uints[0], uints[1], uints[2], uints[3], addrs[3], FeeMethod(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[0]), SaleKindInterface.Side(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[1]), SaleKindInterface.SaleKind(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[2]), addrs[4], AuthenticatedProxy.HowToCall(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[3]), calldataBuy, replacementPatternBuy, addrs[5], staticExtradataBuy, ERC20(addrs[6]), uints[4], uints[5], uints[6], uints[7], uints[8]),
      Sig(vs[0], rssMetadata[0], rssMetadata[1]),
      Order(addrs[7], addrs[8], addrs[9], uints[9], uints[10], uints[11], uints[12], addrs[10], FeeMethod(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[4]), SaleKindInterface.Side(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[5]), SaleKindInterface.SaleKind(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[6]), addrs[11], AuthenticatedProxy.HowToCall(feeMethodsSidesKindsHowToCalls[7]), calldataSell, replacementPatternSell, addrs[12], staticExtradataSell, ERC20(addrs[13]), uints[13], uints[14], uints[15], uints[16], uints[17]),
      Sig(vs[1], rssMetadata[2], rssMetadata[3]),
      rssMetadata[4]
    );
}
```

Comment: I read you can use also `approveOrder_` but not sure what's the difference. As for the inputs, you need to request the sell order you are matching from their API and look for the returned values. Most of the inputs needed for `atomicMatch_` are there.